# How To Retrieve Grid Rows From Grid after Grid Refresh in CRM 2015 Update 1?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

CRM 2015 Update 1 add the ability to create OnLoad Events for grids.  I hooked up an event to a Grid's onLoad event, hoping to get whatever values have been added to the grid, but when I attempt to get the rows, it always returns 0 rows when being called from a registered onLoad event:

```
// Always returns undefined when called from the Grid's onLoad Event, even if the user is just sorting the grid
Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts").getGrid().getRows().get(0);
```

Is there away to get the rows from a Grid after a user adds or removes a row?  The code works fine if it is triggered outside of the Grid OnLoad event.

Comment: I have just created a Vanilla CRM 2015 and i can reproduce your issue

    Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts").getGrid().getRows().getAll()

This return me empty array, seems like its a bit bugy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround but it is not the best way to do.

```
 setTimeout(function () {

    var allGridRowData = [];
    var rows = Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts").getGrid().getRows();
    console.log(rows.length);
    rows.forEach(function (row, i) {
        allGridRowData.push(row.getData().getEntity());
        console.log(allGridRowData);
    });

 }, 2000);
```

It looks that the grid is not fully loaded with the records when he onload is triggered.